# WPF MVVM Can I bind 2 commands to a single ModernButton?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, modern-ui

I might be going completely wrong here but I am trying to perform 2 actions based on a single click of a ModernButton (Part of ModernUI).

Basically I have an 'Add' button on one page.  When a user clicks it I want to call a 'Add' method on my underlying ViewModel and also navigate to a new view.  I currently have this working from 2 separate buttons as a test but want them both working from one.

Example buttons:

```
<mui:ModernButton x:Name="btnAdd" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Project}"/>
<mui:ModernButton x:Name="btnAdd2" Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="/View/pages/ProjectView.xaml"/>
```

I think I am getting confused as its a combination of 1 action on the UI and 1 on the ViewModel underneath.

It seems like a straightforward requirement which makes me think I may be going wrong in my approach.

As always, any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always copy the way Microsoft implements this problem, see the [`CompositeCommand`](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Prism.Mvvm/Commands/CompositeCommand.cs), and either bind directly to this command, or create a multivalueconverter which takes multiple commands and returns a `CompositeCommand`.